# Finding the limit from left

Tags: calculus, limits

I just started calc class and have this problem:

$$\lim_{x\to\pi^-}{\cot x}$$

I'm especially interested in how to use the fact that the limit is from the left. We haven't learnt a lot about limits so I need a simple argument that this approaches negative infinity.

Comment: I've attempted to restate your limit in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), but I might not have preserved your original intent. Please double-check it.

Comment: *Hint* use l'hopital's rule

Answer (score 0):

To prove the claim

> $$\lim_{x \to \pi^-} \cot x = -\infty$$

you can show, for any $y \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $\cot x < y$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $\pi - \varepsilon < x < \pi$.

You can use the fact that $\cot x$ is strictly decreasing on the interval $P = (0, \pi)$; i.e., if $x_1 > x_2$ for $x_1, x_2 \in P$, then $\cot x_1 < \cot x_2$. This makes the problem easier since you just need to show that for any $y \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists some $x_0 \in P$ such that $\cot x_0 \le y$, and take $\varepsilon = \pi - x_0$ to satisfy the previous.

If $y \ge -\sqrt{3}$, take $x_0 = \frac{5 \pi}{6}$, for which $\cot x_0 = -\sqrt{3} \le y$.

If $y < -\sqrt{3}$, take $x_0 = \pi - \frac{1}{y^2}$. I will leave it to you to check that under these circumstances, $x_0 \in P$ and $\cot x_0 < y$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
    f(x)=\lim_{{x\to \pi^{-} }} \cot x 
    &= \lim_{{x\to \pi^{-}}} \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} \nonumber \\
    &= \lim_{{x\to \pi^{-}}} \frac{-1}{\sin x} \nonumber \\
    &= - \infty \nonumber \\
\end{align}